# How to detect the floor/ground plane using unity Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am a newbie to vuforia, I am working on a project based on augmented reality. I wanted to detect the floor as a part of my project.

My question is there any other way to recognize the floor/ground plane other than using the option "Image target" like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIIQPBSO5sg)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an upcoming feature of Vuforia 7: https://www.vuforia.com/press-releases/ptc-announces-major-new-release-to-vuforia-augmented-reality-platform.html

It is not released yet. You can use ARKit (iOS) or ARCore (Android) now.

Comment: Thanks ibrahim, for now i used ARKit (iOS) and its working fine, i will use ARCore (Android) also latter.

Comment: It's released with Unity 2017.3. https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/ground-plane-guide.html

Comment: @GyanenduShekhar did you use that for any purpose?

Comment: @MadLeo how to use ARKit in vuforia? Have you used ARKit in vuforia or separately?

Comment: @Kitwradr separately, because vuforia and ARKit both are different.

Comment: Yes now that vuforia fusion is launched , we can use arcore and arkit in vuforia itself , but I know not of anyone who has done this

Answer (score -1):

You should check this library made by Vuforia: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Getting-Started-with-Smart-Terrain

Comment: do you have any clue or sample link to use this.

Comment: Smart Terrain is a feature that is (about to be) deprecated due to the upcoming Vuforia Fusion in Vuforia 7. This is available currently undocumented in the latest beta of Unity (2017.3.0b8)